# Implementing Search with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was trying to implement search with laravel where i want to submit the form with post method and trying to show the query like this .

```
abc.com/search/q=res
```

Here is my routes :

```
Route::post('productSearch','ProductController@productSearch');
  Route::get('search/q={query}','ProductController@searchProduct');

public function productSearch(Request $request)
    {
        $query = $request->name; 
        return redirect('search/q='.$query);
    }

    public  function searchProduct(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->query;
        $products = DB::table('products')           
            ->select('products.*')              
            ->where('products.name' , 'like', '%'.$name.'%') //Error in this line   

        return view('product',compact('products'));
    }
```

But the problem is it shows the following Error

```
Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag could not be converted to string
```

How do i implement search where in URL in shows in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your route with `Route::get('search','ProductController@searchProduct');`

In the function use `$params = Input::get('q');` to get a variable.

Example to request `search?q=name`

```
public  function searchProduct(Request $request)
    {
        $name = Input::get('q');
        // or this option  
        //$name = $request->input('q');
        $products = DB::table('products')           
            ->select('products.*')              
            ->where('products.name' , 'like', '%'.$name.'%') //Error in this line   

        return view('product',compact('products'));
    }
```

Or define your route `Route::get('search/{search}','ProductController@searchProduct');`

In the function use `public function searchProduct($search)`to get the variable $search

Example to request `abc.com/search/xxxxxxxx`

```
public function productSearch(Request $request)
    {
        $query = $request->name; 
        return redirect('search/'.$query);
    }
public  function searchProduct($search)
    {
        $products = DB::table('products')           
            ->select('products.*')              
            ->where('products.name' , 'like', '%'.$search.'%');   

        return view('product',compact('products'));
    }
```

Comment: when i tried with the second option, the Query doesn't work, means it showing all products data

Comment: @U Use the second form I've posted, and verify that function productSearch is getting $request->name